# The server has returned the following error: invalid enumeration context

Tags: powershell, active-directory

When I run First part it works fine, however, the Second option (which I want to use) does not work and is giving me an error:

> Error getting objects: The server has returned the following error:
>   invalid enumeration context

[I Tried following this article.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/32418.active-directory-troubleshooting-server-has-returned-the-following-error-invalid-enumeration-context.aspx)

I tried result page size with different values but it does not work either. I checked the second Cmdlet with `Measure-Command` and it is taking 17 minutes to fetch AD objects and time out time is mentioned in the ADWS server is 30 minutes.

Could you please help me to understand what is wrong? We do not want to user the first option; we want to import all account irrespective date and time.

I want to remove date filter which I am using in the first option and wanted to to get ad object in a script without mentioning days and should fetch all records old and the new one. Please help experts here :)

---

**First**

```
$from = ((Get-Date).AddDays(-100)).date
         $to = ((Get-Date).AddDays(0)).date

         $A = @(Get-ADUser -Filter { whenCreated -ge $from -and whenCreated -le $to } -Properties * -Server $DomainController)
```

---

**Second**

```
$A = @(Get-ADUser -Filter '*' -Properties * -Server $DomainController)
```

Comment: You say you "followed" the article - what did you attempt to change about your query and how did it work out?

Comment: What properties are actually needed `-Properties *` is going to be slow as it is pulling ___all___ adboject properties, even the non indexed ones. Get the ones you want and you would see improvement there as well.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I tried adding parameter Resultpagesize with different values but did not work....also When I run this second Cmdlet on powershell console It is doing it when I pipe into csv but not as a script ...Please let me know If I miss anything as I am not good with powershell and still learning :)

Comment: @Matt Thanx for the reply, yes you are right, however, I was wondering  Is there a way we can pull all properties as you can see we are doing in the first Cmdlet which I mentioned. 

I am trying to remove date variable so that we don't have to manually manage this and it should work it self and import all account regardless date.

Comment: Basically, I want to remove Filter

Comment: Is there something which can be done in the first option to remove filter and retrieve all properties ? Your help would be highly appreciated!